# Force Video.js player to stick to edges of browser (responsive?)

Tags: html, css, html5-video, video.js

There have been a few questions on this matter and sadly for me none of them have worked.

First I want to show you a screenshot so you understand what I am asking for

[image: video player not positioned correctly and videojs controlbar is hidden]

Here is my current code for the embed:

```html
<div class="embedded clear-adblock">
   <div style="position: relative !important; width: 100% !important; height: auto !important;">
      {% include '@themePath/account/partial/_preview_video_'~videoPlayer~'.html.twig' with {'IS_EMBED': IS_EMBED} %}
   </div>
</div>
```

I have tried adjusting width and height, height with 0 and auto. Played around with positioning and vjs fluid is enabled

Answer (score 0):

As in video.js there will be  **Dynamically rendered classes**  after you run the HTML file on the browser . So , **Don't** put inline css on the embed , inspect the video element and you will get the necessary classes , after you found those essential classes from that video container , **style that as you want using embedded css** on the same page , I think this will help you .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this right after posting this question by removing vjs fluid from videojs and using the following CSS in div:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
```